# Appending Item to dropdown list without selecting the item

Tags: jquery, selected

I have a form wherr I fill in an item name and immediately after I hit submit the item adds to the select dropdownlist and is automatically selected. Is there a way not to have this newly added item selected?

My code that adds the item looks like this

```
$("#userGroup_groups").append("<option value="41" selected="selected">item</option>");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

remove `selected`

```
$("#userGroup_groups").append("<option value=\"41\" >item</option>");
```

Comment: some time it's happen...don't worry we are here for such stuffs...:)

Answer (score 1):

Don't set the new items `selected` property

```
$("#userGroup_groups").append('<option value="41">item</option>');
```

Comment: and you should escape quotes inside :)

Answer (score 0):

check page post back on page_load event and set AutoPostBack="true" in asp:ddl control

```
  if (!IsPostBack) {
                LoadInfoDDL();
            }
```

so this will only resolve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

You must use combination of the " and ' while doing things like this

```
$("#userGroup_groups").append(
    "<option value='41' selected='selected'>item</option>"
);
```

Comment: Okay. May I ask why?